# MyBatis Generator setDistinct(true)

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I'm trying to use `setDistinct(true)` as it is described in the guide: http://mybatis.github.io/generator/generatedobjects/exampleClassUsage.html

I've written in this way:

```
testExample ae = new testExample();    
testExample.Criteria criteriatest = ae.createCriteria(); 
ae.setDistinct(true); 
criteriatest.andIDENTLAVEqualTo(Long.parseLong(cert.getCODINDIVID())); 
ae.or(criteriatest); 
List<test> listtest = testMapper.selectByExample(ae);
```

but the `setDistinct(true)` doesn't affect the results.

Where should I add the setDistinct line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the link you referenced is for an extremely old version of *MyBatis*. On that page, it lists the following:

> Version: 1.3.3-SNAPSHOT

The latest version is:

> mybatis-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT

Grepping the 3.x code for `setDistinct` does not return anything:
https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/search?q=setDistinct

I'm surprised you don't get a compile-time error about the method not being found. Are you using *version 1.3.3* (or 1.x)?

I would recommend doing the `DISTINCT` right in the query. Since *MyBatis* is generally a sort of a *close-to-the-SQL-metal* type of mapping framework, I think it's best to add it in the mapper file's query itself. Plus that way, you can choose specifically what to `DISTINCT` by. The `setDistinct` method does not seem to provide any way to specify the target.

For *MyBatis 3*, I think the analogous style of query would be this:

http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/statement-builders.html

This seems to be analogous to a *jOOQ*-style *DSL*. It has a `SELECT_DISTINCT` method. I personally find it easier to code/read the *pure SQL* with some *XML markup* as needed for dynamic SQL in a *mapper file*, but this is certainly a viable option in *MyBatis 3*.

**Edit:**

So, I did some more digging, and the reason I couldn't find the code in the *MyBatis3* git repo is because `setDistinct` is in the *mybatis-generator* code base.

I think part of the issue here may stem from what is part of *Mybatis-Generator*'s description on *GitHub*:

> MBG seeks to make a major impact on the large percentage of database
>   operations that are simple CRUD (Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete).

So, it provides a way to do simple `DISTINCT`s, but with limited control.

The code resides in the `addClassElements` method of the `ProviderSelectByExampleWithoutBLOBsMethodGenerator` class. Searching for `setDistinct` won't show up on a Github search since it's an automatically generated *setter*.

This is the relevant [code snippet](https://github.com/mybatis/generator/blob/master/core/mybatis-generator-core/src/main/java/org/mybatis/generator/codegen/mybatis3/javamapper/elements/sqlprovider/ProviderSelectByExampleWithoutBLOBsMethodGenerator.java):

```
boolean distinctCheck = true;
        for (IntrospectedColumn introspectedColumn : getColumns()) {
            if (distinctCheck) {
                method.addBodyLine("if (example != null && example.isDistinct()) {"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                method.addBodyLine(String.format("%sSELECT_DISTINCT(\"%s\");", //$NON-NLS-1$
                 builderPrefix,
                    escapeStringForJava(getSelectListPhrase(introspectedColumn))));
                method.addBodyLine("} else {"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                method.addBodyLine(String.format("%sSELECT(\"%s\");", //$NON-NLS-1$
                 builderPrefix,
                    escapeStringForJava(getSelectListPhrase(introspectedColumn))));
                method.addBodyLine("}"); //$NON-NLS-1$
            } else {
                method.addBodyLine(String.format("%sSELECT(\"%s\");", //$NON-NLS-1$
                 builderPrefix,
                    escapeStringForJava(getSelectListPhrase(introspectedColumn))));
            }

            distinctCheck = false;
        }
```

So, essentially, this looks like it's wrapping the `SELECT_DISTINCT` method I mentioned originally, and it attempts to introspect the columns and apply the `DISTINCT` to all of the ones it gets back.

Digging a bit deeper, it ultimately calls this code to get the columns:

```
/**
* Returns all columns in the table (for use by the select by primary key
* and select by example with BLOBs methods)
*
* @return a List of ColumnDefinition objects for all columns in the table
*/
    public List<IntrospectedColumn> getAllColumns() {
        List<IntrospectedColumn> answer = new ArrayList<IntrospectedColumn>();
        answer.addAll(primaryKeyColumns);
        answer.addAll(baseColumns);
        answer.addAll(blobColumns);

        return answer;
    }
```

So, this is definitely essentially an all-or-nothing `DISTINCT` (whereas *Postgres* itself allows `DISTINCT` on just certain columns).

Try moving the `setDistinct` to the very last line before you actually invoke the `ae` object. Perhaps subsequent calls are affecting the column set (although from the code, it doesn't seem like it should -- basically once the columns are set, the `setDistinct` should use them).

The other thing that would be interesting would be to see what SQL it is actually generating with and without `setDistinct`.

Check this link out for more detail on debug/logging:

http://mybatis.github.io/generator/reference/logging.html

I'd recommend perhaps trying out the XML-based mapper file definitions which interleave *SQL* with *XML* tags for dynamic-ness. IMO, it's much easier to follow than the code *Mybatis Generator* code snippet above. I suppose that's one of the main tradeoffs with a generator -- easier to create initially, but more difficult to read/maintain later.

For super-dynamic queries, I could see some more advantages, but then that sort of goes against their self-description of it being for **simple CRUD** operations.

Comment: I see. I use mybatis-3.2.7,  mybatis-spring-1.2.2 and mybatis-generator-1.3.2. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I was debugging some code and I found that there is a check on the setDistinct.

Comment: Added add'l info to answer.